# JQuery Get method with parameters or AJAX is not working with Phonegap?

Tags: jquery, get, cordova

I'm doing an application with Phonegap (Cordova), and, altough, the $.post and $.get function works most of the time, the following code is not working:

```
$.get(urlLastPosition + '?taxi_id=16')
    .done(function(data){
          lat = data.latitude;
          lon = data.longitude;
          });
```

I have tried with AJAX method but it is still not working,

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://arcane-lowlands-6512.herokuapp.com/positions/get_last.json?taxi_id=16',
   success: function(data){
   lat = data.latitude;
   lon = data.longitude;
   console.log(data.id);
   },
   dataType: 'JSON'
   });
```

And as I said before this $.get method does work

```
$.get(taxiUrl + "/" + taxId + ".json")
.done(function(data){
      drivId = data.current_driver_id;
      result.push(data.installation_id);
      });
```

Also I have tried it on the browser and it works, using chrome as well as Postman (extension). 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet is working for me. All of them is working in a browser for you too, right? You should try adding the error handler too, so you might get some message...

Comment: Is this a CORS request?

Comment: I don't really know what a CORS Request is. And yes it is working on my browser, I did add the lines of jqXHR with fail(), done(), always() and it only get to always(), so there is not really an error, altough debuging it doesn't send back any ResponseText, is really weird, as I said the only difference in this $.get is that i'm sending some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that the answer was taking some time on the phone, and given that it is an asynchronous call it was not taking any return. Given that, I have to applied what I found in here

[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Using the answer about **promise** using it, as soon as the data was available the function is call and use. That's how I end up fixing the problem.